# How to make a has_and_belongs_to_many association when creating an instance of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
c = Course.create name:"Math1", ??
```

I'm trying to figure out how to associate this course to the existing students with has_and_belongs_to_many. Below is my schema with the associations. I'm having trouble creating instances of each and putting in their specific associations.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170127225124) do

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "students_courses", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "students_id"
    t.integer "courses_id"
    t.index ["courses_id"], name: "index_students_courses_on_courses_id"
    t.index ["students_id"], name: "index_students_courses_on_students_id"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. in a has_and_belongs_to_many association you don't need to worry about the middle table. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) you can find the methods added to the model by this type of association.

So, one way you can do this is by passing an array of the students ids, like:

```
student = Student.create username: "John"
c = Course.create name: "Math1", student_ids: [student.id]
```

You could also use the create method:

```
c.students.create({username: "John"})
```

Also, be careful with your join table. By default rails expect it to be in the alphabetical order, so would be `courses_students` instead. For that purpose I usually prefer to use the `create_join_table` command(reference [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table)).